# Unit managing function c++

Tags: c++

```
string update_unit(const string &s){
    istringstream iss(s);
    string word;
    map<string, int> bank;
    while (iss >> word){
        auto found = word.find('^');
        int power = 0;
        string temp_unit;
        if (found != string::npos){
            power = stoi(word.substr(found+1));
            string temp_unit = word.substr(0, found);
        }else{
            string temp_unit = word;
            power = 1;
        }

        if (bank.find(temp_unit)==bank.end()){
            bank[temp_unit] = power;
        }else{
            bank[temp_unit] += power;
        }

    }

    for (auto [x,y]:bank){
        cout << x << y << endl;
    }

    std::ostringstream total;
    for (auto [temp, power] : bank){
        if (power == 1){
            total << temp << ' ';
        }
        else if(power > 1){
            total << temp << '^' << power << ' ';
        }
    }
   return total.str().substr(0, total.str().length()-1);
}
```

Example Input and expected output are as follows:

```
string input = "feet^-1 second^3 feet^2 second^-2";
string expected = "feet^1 second^1";
string my_output = "^2";
```

We assume that all the units in the input are supposed to be multiplied, thus the given expected output.
My approach was to use a istringstream to split the string into words, create a map that stores all units with their respective powers, and then I can combine all of them to get the desired output, but it did not work as I expected. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: sorry, me again. This question has the same problem as your last: There is no question. Try to be more specific. "Any help" is a sign that your question is too broad, opinion-based, unclear or all together

Comment: There is something wrong with my code, and I don't know what it is.

Comment: then explain what is wrong. If the output does not match the expected output then include the actual output, and please include a [mcve] that enables others to reproduce that output

Comment: My goal is to go over the string, word by word, and store the unit and its power in a map. If we come across the same unit again, we update the power of that particular unit in the map. But I think there is a problem with how I am reading words into the stringstream.

Comment: I've written my output in the second code block

Comment: sorry missed that

Comment: I did a bit of checking, and found that the part where I try to create string temp_unit is not working and I am just getting blank spaces.

Comment: string temp_unit = word.substr(0, found);

Comment: This very line to be very precise

Comment: It's not a rule, but if you give your function a really good name so that everyone knows what it does - so will you when implementing it.

If it's hard to give it a name - consider splitting it up into 2 functions.

Repeat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redeclare a `string` called `temp_unit` twice. Here:

```
string temp_unit = word.substr(0, found);
```

and here

```
string temp_unit = word;
```

Because their scope is more narrow than the one of the actual `temp_unit` you don't get an error. If you fix that, the code produces the expected output:

```
    if (found != string::npos){
        power = stoi(word.substr(found+1));
        temp_unit = word.substr(0, found);
    }else{
        temp_unit = word;
        power = 1;
    }
```

Also note that instead of

```
    if (bank.find(temp_unit)==bank.end()){
        bank[temp_unit] = power;
    }else{
        bank[temp_unit] += power;
    }
```

you can simply write

```
bank[temp_unit] += power;
```

The `map::operator[]` inserts a default constructred value for the key if it does not exist yet.

PS: Your expected output is off. In your code you have a special case for `power==1` that does not add the `^1` part to the output. Also you miss to handle negative powers.

Comment: Aah gotcha, thank you. Can you explain the special case you are talking about?

Comment: @NikitParakh you do not put anything in the result `total` when the power is negative